# Where to handle Roles in an MVC Application (C#, WebApi)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, c#-4.0, model-view-controller, asp.net-web-api

I'm currently working on an application which allows users with multiple Roles to select one which is then used throughout the application to display content and perform actions for that particular role (It's not about authorisation which is handled separately).  The current code base is littered with "if role == "x" else" statements and similar constructs in the Controller and Views.

Some code has now be moved into services which raises the question where should Roles be handled?  I don't think Views should have knowledge of the Roles but I'm not so sure about Services.

The options are for ex. passing the selected role into a service or providing specialised service methods for each role separately and have the controller choose which one to use.

Comment: Making users select a role somehow sounds like an uncommon idea. Rather, consider having different endpoints (urls), one for each role and validate the membership upon call. No need to choose anything this way.

Comment: We allow users to "override" their roles in test environments.  What we do is use a custom identity that tracks "overridden" roles as well as their base roles.  We only have to do this in a global event after the user is authorized normally.  Then we check User.IsInRole() normally everywhere else.

Comment: I agree but this is unfortunately not an option at the moment.